# How Zip method works

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have been looking Zip method so i can run a object with a structure like this  and i've made this code:

```
var column = from col in database.ColumnReference select col.ColumnSourceName;

var table = from tab in database.TableSourceReference where tab.TableID.Equals
                       (from col in database.ColumnReference select col.TableID) select tab.TableName;

var columnTable = column.Zip(table, (a, b) => new { Column = a, Table = b });
```

but it doesn't work. I try with another example:

```
 int[] t1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
 int[] t2 = { 4, 5, 6 };
 var temp = t1.Zip(t2, (a, b) => new { tmp1 = t1, tmp2 = t2 });
```

and when i run foreach it works fine.

Why does it happens?
thk

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: it would help to provide what you're expecting to get vs. what you actually get in the case where it 'doesn't work'...

Comment: Not every Linq method is supported by every Linq provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var table = from tab in database.TableSourceReference where tab.TableID.Equals
                   (from col in database.ColumnReference select col.TableID) select tab.TableName;
```

This makes no sense as you are asking for the `TableSourceReference` where the `TableID` equals a collection of ids.

I think what you really want is a join between the columns and the tables.

For example:

```
from col in database.ColumnReference
join tab in database.TableSourceReference
    on col.TableID equals tab.TableID
select new { Column = col, Table = tab}
```

Comment: my table columnReference has this structure

public int ColumnID { get; set; }
        public string ColumnSourceName { get; set; }
        public string ColumnDestinationName { get; set; }
        public int TableID { get; set; }
        public virtual TableSourceReference TableSourceReference { get; set; }

and i want to when i'm reading the column name to know to which table it belongs, that's why i was using the zip method so when i read the column i also read the table